# Boot very slow because of drm_kms_helper errors

Tags: 16.04, boot, intel-graphics, drm

I just installed 16.04 on my MacBook Air, and everything seems to work well, except booting the system. I've been going through the `dmesg`-log and found out that `drm_kms_helper`-errors occur repeatedly and takes a lot of time each. The excact error is like this:

```
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out
```

The `CRTC`-value and the `pipe`-value varies, but otherwise all the errors are identical.

What does this mean and how do I fix it? If it can't be fixed, how do I prevent it from using so much time when booting?

Comment: Follow this link to resolve your issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZhOm_qYL-o

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a bug. To avoid delay you can use workaround. From terminal run:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Then add the kernel boot parameter: `video=SVIDEO-1:d`, so it will look like this:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"`

2. `sudo update-grub`
3. `sudo reboot`

Comment: didn't work for me :(

Comment: Works very well on Macbook with ElementaryOS too :)

Comment: with this boot parameter the boot time improved from about 3 Minutes to 20 seconds (ubuntu 18.04)  with a Intel GM965 graphic

Comment: Fixed issue on Arch Linux on Lenovo ThinkPad R61i.

Comment: It work on my old Intel Pentium Dual-core 32bit, lubuntu 16

Comment: This also worked on an Acer 4720Z

Comment: please follow this link to resolve your issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZhOm_qYL-o

Comment: On an old Dell Inspiron 1525, I was running 16, then upgraded to 18 and got this issue. I downgraded back, but it didn't fix it. This answer fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: worked on inspiron 1525

Comment: Worked on HP Compaq 6710b. It made the laptop usable again.... (everything was TERRIBLY slow without this).

Comment: Worked for me, vastly improved startup time!

2008 Macbook (model 4,1, white polycarbonate, 2.4 GHz model). Running Lubuntu 18.10, 64 bit version using rEFInd.

Comment: Works fine with Intel Pentium Dual T2330 (-MCP-) and Xubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked on Compaq 610 Intel Core2Duo and Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Comment: Worked on Macbook Air 1,1 and Centos 7

Comment: Worked for me on Lubuntu, version of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Worked for MAcbook 4,1 (white ) and Debian 10. Besides boot time, also fixed problems with ethernet card

Answer (score 4):

I have still this problem after adding video=SVIDEO-1:d to **grub** like described above.

But I found this entry (https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/51703) with this comment:

> Comment by Luis Bourgard (unnilquadium) - Friday, 26 January 2018,
>   19:08 GMT 
>   Still present in 4.14.14 It only happens with the
>   xf86-video-intel package installed (running on a laptop with intel
>   integrated graphics on an i5-2410m). Uninstalling that package fixes
>   the issue, but it also introduces some screen tearing.

I removed the package with **sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel**. Maybe this works for us.

For screen-tearing correction, these ideas may also help (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233957):

> Post by jaylittle - 2018-06-25 21:54:22 
>   If you want to solve your screen tearing issue in Xfce without 
>   relying upon the broken intel xorg driver, just disable the built 
>   in Xfce compositor and run something like compton as part of your 
>   session startup.  That should resolve your issue with screen tearing 
>   and allow you to use the more reputable kms driver.

Comment: Exactly! Removing xf86-video-intel fixed the issue. This package is recommended to avoid everywhere!

Comment: Don't working on my old intel pentium dual-core 32bit with lubuntu 16