# [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* on Ubuntu 16.04, dell vostro 1510 intel core 2: x error + wireless error + and drm_kms_helper error , at start process

Tags: boot, kernel, xorg, drm

**QUESTION**

- Is it possible to ask to ubuntu 16.04 LTS developpers to solve kernel error due to bad relationship process with intel ship on dell vostro 1510 generating xorg graphic errors and network errors?
- Bellow the problem description, the solution found, but requiring to overwrite code in grubb, which is not very normal, does it ?

**Configuration:**

- Hardware: DELL VOSTRO 1510, intel core 2 duo
- Ubuntu version: 16.04 LTS
- Kernel version: 4.13.0-45-generic

**What was expected:**

- The computer should boot without problem, from start to the environement connexion. The connexion to network should work.

**What happend and was not expected (the problem):**

- During the boot process of the computer, before the access to the connexion windows, a couple of windows appears, saying: ".../... starting on low graphic mode" and "you would have to define graphic .../... by yourself".
- After those windows, the connexion windows appears later, but when connected to the work environment, connexion to wireless and network are impossible.

**Findings of drm_kms_helper ERRORS in start process messages**

- To discover what happened during the starting process, the dmesg is used in command line in a terminal, and it returns tons of errors. Some appears in red in terminal text returns. Those red texts are copy/paste bellow:

  dmesg

  .../...
  [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:35:pipe B] flip_done timed out
  .../...

**Finding some similar errors on askubuntu.com for 16.04 LTS:**

- Searching on the internets the whole text of the error above and adding Ubuntu 16.04 TLS, it returns a askubuntu.com discussion: [drm_kms_helper ERROR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors)
- This solution suggests to add a piece of code on grubb (see answer 2 of the above linked discussion). The piece of code suggested to be added in grub is:

  video=SVIDEO-1:d

**Applying the solution above**

- Open grub to write in it, using terminal command:

  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
- Then add the kernel boot parameter: video=SVIDEO-1:d, so it will look like this:

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"
- Then, update and reboot

  sudo update-grub
  sudo reboot

**Effects of solution: problem solved**

After having applied this solution, the dell vostro 1510 with intel core 2 duo under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS boot without error, network connexion work fine again.