# After login: [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out

Tags: kernel, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and +/- 1 minute after logging in my laptop gets extremely slow and I get lots of `drm_atomic_helper` errors (`flip_done` timed out). When switching to a text console everything seems fine. The boot process itself is not slow.

This happens with kernels 4.15.0-29 and 4.15.0-30 but **not with 4.15.0.24**.

The laptop is a Dell XPS 13 (9370) and the graphics chip is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

I tried adding `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to the boot parameters but the problem is still the same.

A part of the syslog is below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:78
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:77
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2240]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [   61.523178] rfkill: input handler enabled
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [   62.275790] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [   72.511181] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [   82.748672] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:28:plane 1A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [   92.986813] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [  103.225879] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [  113.465111] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:28:plane 1A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [  123.704451] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [  133.943846] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [  144.183754] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:28:plane 1A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:15:57 boson kernel: [  154.427568] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:16:27 boson kernel: [  164.663485] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:16:27 boson kernel: [  174.903069] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:28:plane 1A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:16:27 boson kernel: [  185.142853] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:37:pipe A] flip_done timed out
Aug  8 10:16:51 boson kernel: [  209.218455] nf_conntrack: default automatic helper assignment has been turned off for security reasons and CT-based  firewall rule not found. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
Aug  8 10:17:00 boson systemd[1]: Started Session 6 of user hans.
Aug  8 10:17:01 boson CRON[5720]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  8 10:18:01 boson CRON[6484]: (hans) CMD (offlineimap >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors

Comment: I also have this problem and the difference to the link provided by @RoyceWilliams is that boot process isn't slow. The lags appear after the login.