# 18.04 LTS Live Medium won't boot - drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper] Error

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, live-usb

I'm trying to set up a HP Compaq 6720s laptop with Linux for my mum. This is her 2nd notebook, the 1st one was an old Celeron running Mint 17.1. So thats why I started again with LM 18.3.

I had it all setup running LM 18.3 on a regular HDD and it worked fine. I installed the updates and then boot time just skyrocketed, I'm talking about 10-15 min before being able to use the laptop. I used the workaround found [here](http://Hey%20guys,%20%20I'm%20trying%20to%20set%20up%20a%20HP%20Compaq%206720s%20laptop%20with%20for%20my%20mum%20with%20Linux%20Mint.%20I%20had%20it%20all%20setup%20running%2018.3%20on%20a%20regular%20HDD%20and%20it%20worked%20fine.%20I%20installed%20the%20updates%20and%20then%20boot%20time%20just%20skyrocketed,%20I'm%20talking%20about%2010-15%20min%20before%20being%20able%20to%20use%20the%20laptop.%20I%20used%20the%20workaround%20found%20here,%20as%20showing%20the%20same%20errors.%20After%20that%20everything%20worked%20great,%20fast%20boot...%20In%20the%20meantime%20I%20got%20a%20hand%20on%20a%20SSD%20and%20Tara%20was%20released%20so%20I%20thought%20of%20switching%20both.%20Now%20is%20the%20problem%20that%20I%20can't%20boot%20into%20the%20Live%20medium.%20The%20same%20error%20messages%20are%20shown%20during%20boot%20([drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done%20[drm_kms_helper]]%20*ERROR*%20[CRTC:26:pipe%20A]%20flip_done%20timed%20out),%20and%20I%20get%20to%20Mint%20logo%20with%20the%205%20dots.%20It%20doesn't%20matter%20which%20way%20I%20create%20the%20USB%20install%20medium%20(rufus,%20Unetbootin,%20Etcher)%20or%20if%20I%20use%20Sarah%20or%20Tara.%20I%20onced%20managed%20to%20boot%20using%20the%20compatibility%20mode%20but%20during%20install%20the%20installer%20just%20cancelled%20the%20install%20during%20file%20copying.), as it was showing the same errors. After that everything worked great, fast boot...
In the meantime I got a hand on a SSD and Tara was released so I thought of switching both. Now is the problem that I can't boot into the Live medium, not LM19, not Ubuntu 18.04. The same error messages are shown during boot: `[drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip_done timed out`, and I get to thelogo with the 5 dots. It doesn't matter which way I create the USB install medium (rufus, Unetbootin, Etcher) or if I use Mint or Ubuntu(-flavours). I onced managed to boot using the compatibility mode but during install the installer just kept crashing.

Here the outputs of [inxi](https://pastebin.com/raw/Ar2najsy) & [lcpi](https://pastebin.com/raw/0nturaQS).

And the pic for errors presented in initram, I think:
[errors initram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XzEB.jpg)

Any help of getting it running would be great, and especially my mum would be thrilled to finally start using a dualcore machine and 4GB RAM.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors

Comment: My problem is not about slow boot of an installed OS, but the failure of booting from live-usb completely.

Comment: That link covers the error you are getting.  Forget about the slow part.

Comment: OK for the first install on the HDD I did exactly as described above, actually i put a link in my OP to exactly that topic. But how do I edit the grub menu on a live-usb?

Comment: Your link for the workaround is blank.  But that is OK.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions on how to change kernel options for an Ubuntu LiveCD

Comment: Thx Terrance for pointing out the apparently obvious thing :) as noob it's not always easy to connect the dots. Anyway, installed, updated, using :) I'm just curious, why did I still saw the error messages drm_kms_helper while booting from live_usb even thought I set the boot options to "video=SVIDEO-1:d"?