# Ubuntu server 18.04 slow boot due to drm_kms_helper

Tags: boot, server, kms

I have installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on an old notebook for home purposes (SAMBA, Transmission, etc...). When I open it, it shows me [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw6G9.jpg). It remains for about 2-3 minutes and it slows the boot process.
How can I remove this screen?

Comment: There's a better way to identify the culprit of a slow boot. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Answer (score 0):

This was identified as a bug in Ubuntu 16.04 and persisted into 18.04.1 for both servers and desktops. Re 16.04 see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1685442 where the last line of that thread says that a fix was (finally!) released on 2019-01-25. I presume that fix was simultaneously applied to 18.04 as well, which would mean that the normal updates you periodically apply to your system would resolve the problem without additional intervention.

If not, see [Boot very slow because of drm_kms_helper errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors) for a very easy and complete fix that works on 18.04 as well as 16.04. It cuts boot time by around 70 or 80%.