# Long Kernel Boot Segment in 18.04

Tags: boot, kernel

I need help figuring out why the 1st "Kernel" section of boot time shown by "systemd-analyze plot" is 67 seconds long. How do I debug that part of the boot process?

I've been looking around and see a lot of posts discussing various things that either don't apply to my system or didn't make much difference.

-- apt-daily.service was running during boot so I followed instructions to create an override.conf file and removed it from the boot sequence. No real improvement, but it's not part of boot anymore.

-- I see reports about bugs in the 4.15.0-24 kernel but I run 4.15.0-43-generic.

-- I see discussions about swap partitions, but I don't have one. Posts I read say 18.04 uses swap files and they are just fine vs. having a swap partition.

-- When I run "systemd-analyze critical-chain" the first several entries (starting with "graphical.target") all end in @52.342s but I'm not sure what they mean.

-- The top several entries from "systemd-analyze blame" are

------- 31.636s for lightdm.service

------- 31.625s for plymouth-quit-wait.service

------- 14.750s for dev-sda1.device

------- 9.733s for systemd-journal-flush.service

------- and then it's keyboard, network, disks and stuff under 7 seconds each after that.

-- I like hibernation so I didn't play with the "noresume" setting in Grub.

This problem started when I decided to try 18.04 on a spare laptop. I reformatted the whole 750GB drive into one single EXT4 partition by rewriting the previous partition table. That worked fine and I installed 18.04 from a live CD.

I previously ran 16.04 and 18.04 on this same machine with no problems. The first version of 18.04 was an update from 16.04 but had functional problems.  I decided to retry 18.04 as a clean install on a clean disk and that's when the speed problem started.

So, any ideas how to figure this out? I want to lend this laptop to a friend as a trial step into linux and having a long boot time like this will be a turn off for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 1520 and there is a bug in the kernel that affects those laptops. It tries to start an svideo adapter, which the laptop doesn't have.

This post has the solution: [Boot very slow because of drm_kms_helper errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors)

The solution is to disable the svideo connector using grub at boot up.

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Add the kernel boot parameter: video=SVIDEO-1:d, so it will look like this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"

sudo update-grub
sudo reboot