# Ubuntu Mate 18.04 Slow Boot and Login (Clean Install)

Tags: boot, 18.04, services, ubuntu-mate

I recently installed Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on my old laptop. It has 3 GB of RAM and Intel Core2Duo processor.

It takes long time to get to the login screen and more waiting to get to the desktop after entering password.

I have boot screen disabled using `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` by changing the file `/etc/default/grub`.

I have tried everything described in [the answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04) but no luck so far !

`/dev/sda3` is the partition where Ubuntu is installed. The benchmark of this partition gives `average read rate 44.9 MB/s` and `average access time 13.28 msec`, so it is not an issue with the HDD.

Output from `systemd-analyze blame`,

> ```
>      45.669s dev-sda3.device
>      33.585s systemd-journal-flush.service
>      25.686s apt-daily.service
>      21.490s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
>      13.915s loadcpufreq.service
>      11.823s grub-common.service
>      11.094s apparmor.service
>      10.979s snapd.seeded.service
>      10.867s networking.service
>      10.325s speech-dispatcher.service
>       9.986s networkd-dispatcher.service
>       9.931s rsyslog.service
>       9.931s gpu-manager.service
>       9.930s pppd-dns.service
>       9.900s apport.service
>       9.480s alsa-restore.service
>       9.463s lm-sensors.service
>       8.987s bluetooth.service
>       8.987s thermald.service
>       8.951s avahi-daemon.service
>       8.250s dev-loop7.device
>       7.847s dev-loop10.device
>       7.808s dev-loop9.device
> ```

Output from `systemd-analyze time`,

> Startup finished in 1min 39.563s (kernel) + 1min 26.728s (userspace) =
>   3min 6.292s graphical.target reached after 1min 663ms in userspace

Output from `systemd-analyze critical-chain`,

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 663ms
└─multi-user.target @1min 662ms
  └─snapd.seeded.service @49.682s +10.979s
    └─snapd.service @1min 400ms +253ms
      └─basic.target @39.421s
        └─sockets.target @39.419s
          └─snapd.socket @39.188s +228ms
            └─sysinit.target @39.183s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @38.808s +371ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @38.564s +174ms
                  └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.970s +33.585s
                    └─systemd-journald.service @4.128s +837ms
                      └─systemd-journald-dev-log.socket @4.122s
                        └─system.slice @3.927s
                          └─-.slice @3.863s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following error in the `dmesg` output,

> [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR
>   [CONNECTOR:50:SVIDEO-1] flip_done timed out

I followed [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors) and changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=SVIDEO-1:d"`.

It fixed the issue.

More references,

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1534300

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109776