# Fresh Ubuntu on SSD dual mode with Win 10 is extremely SLOW

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, performance

I just downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed in dual mode with Win 10 on SSD drive. It is extremely slow. for example the boot takes more than 10 minutes!!! At first when starts gives the attached error screen.
Can somebody help?
[Error Message when Ubuntu wants to start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wun7S.png)
The error message says:
"flip_done timed out"

Comment: Add the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors) and the first answer solved my problem.
To be more exact I did the following and it solved my issue:

> 1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
> 2. Then add the kernel boot parameter: `video=SVIDEO-1:d`, so it will look like this: >`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"`
> 3. `sudo update-grub`
> 4. `sudo reboot`

NOTE: The above solution is copied from [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893817/boot-very-slow-because-of-drm-kms-helper-errors) and it is suggested by [Jan Dostrasil](https://askubuntu.com/users/690116/jan-dostrasil).